# Why wont my program draw the lines between 10 mouseclicks?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program that will draw lines between 10 coordinates, determined by mouseclicks.

i can not get it to work.
code:

EDIT:

i figured out i have to define the coordinates making x and y values.
only it is still unclear how to do this.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point[] punten = new Point[2];
    int index = 0;
    int kliks = 0;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point[] punten = new Point[2];
    int index = 0;
    int kliks = 0;
    kliks = kliks + 1;
    index = kliks;
    punten[index] = e.Location;

    if (index < 2)
    {
        punten[index] = e.Location;
    }
    else
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue);
        Graphics papier = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        papier.DrawLines(pen, punten);
    }
}
```

I have re read the textbook 10 times.. its unclear where to create the variables intially, but if i dont create them under pictureBox1 mouse click, i also cant use them.
Any help is appreciated.

greetings, Stefan.

Comment: To help you understand what you are missing you need to learn about [Variable Scopes in C#](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/variable-scopes-in-csharp).

Comment: `pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();` You should NOT be using `CreateGraphics()` as that is a TEMPORARY drawing surface. Your lines will be erased when the window refreshes (minimize it, for instance, or drag another window across yours after lines have been drawn). Instead, use `e.Graphics` supplied to you in the `Paint()` event of the PictureBox. Also, I'd move to a `List<Point>` instead of an array so that it will grow automatically as you add points to it. In the Paint() event, you can simply call `.ToArray()` against the List to pass it to `DrawLines()`.

Answer (score 0):

The Scope a variables is defined determines its accessibility within the process. You need to declare the `punten` array and the `kliks` int variables at the class level so they can be maintained across the button clicks.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

// create variables at class scope so they are 
// accessible by all methods in this class and state is maintained
// across button clicks
private Point[] punten; 
private int kliks;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // initialize class level variables at form load
    punten = new Point[10];            
    kliks = 0;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int index = kliks;
    if(index == 9) // arrays are zero based so our 10 items are at indexes 0 through 9
    {
        // append last mouse point clicked to list of points
        punten[index] = new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);

        // draw lines between all points
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue);
        Graphics papier = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        papier.DrawLines(pen, punten);   
        punten = new Point[10];
        kliks = 0;             
    }
    else
    {
        // append mouse point clicked to list of points
        punten[index] = new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
        kliks = kliks + 1;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks on the hint for solving where to declare variables. The code you provided gives an error when running the program, error: nullreferenceexception was unhandled.

Comment: it does this at this line:  punten[index] = new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);

Comment: @StefanN I think I fixed the issue, I didn't properly reset the variables after the first line was drawn.

Answer (score 0):

i got it to work!

i need to keep telling my damn self: its all in the textbook...
with the explanations given by you guys (declaring variables at class level)
the instructions in the textbook work..

code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Point[] punten = new Point[10];
        private int kliks = 0;
        private int lijst = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            kliks = kliks + 1;
            lijst = kliks;
            punten[lijst] = e.Location;

            if (lijst < 5)
                

            {
                punten[lijst] = e.Location;

                }

            else
            {

                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue);
                Graphics papier = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
                papier.DrawLines(pen, punten);
            }
        }
    }
}
```